# Magento 1.9 cron running, but stops on one method

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I have a small bug and have no clue where or how to debug. I have one cron task which runs on production but stops or stuck always on one method. On local env it works like a charm, but on prod not. Here is my code:

```
$stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            if ($store->getIsActive()) {

                Mage::log("store ID " . $store->getId() . ": " . $store->getCode(), null, 'myextension.log');

                // call update check
                Mage::log( "before runUpdateCheck()", null, 'myextension.log');

                $update_done = Mage::helper('privacypolicy/service')->runUpdateCheck($store);
                Mage::log( "after runUpdateCheck()", null, 'myextension.log');


                if ($update_done AND ! $updated) {
                    $updated = true;
                }
            }

            Mage::log('Cron: Update check finished', null, 'myextension.log');
        }
```

So it works until `$update_done = Mage::helper('privacypolicy/service')->runUpdateCheck($store);`

Then nothing happened. Tried to add logging into this method. Nothing happened.

As I mentioned above - on local it works fine. Have no idea how to fix it on prod.

Comment: Check your php version.

Comment: @SohelRana `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:00:37)`

Comment: Did you check php error_log?

Comment: @SohelRana of course. I've checked all logs which could tell me any info. They are doesn't contain any errors or issues related to this cron tast

Comment: @SohelRana just FYI. You were almost right about PHP version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this issue by myself. Problem was in PHP version. Before it was 5.5, updated to 7.2 and it solved this problem.